# Listbox multiple selection always selected all

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have one problem with listbox.

I use a listbox and the count is added when selecting the listbox items. But I have two items in the listbox that are always selected and the count is always 2.

What do I do to select a single or mutiple selection?

Comment: do you want single selection??? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh - They've already had to set that property to enable multiple selection (single is the default).

Comment: *But i have two items in listbox that is always selected and the count is always 2* - If you have 2 items that are always selected in the listbox then would you expect a different count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fact is you've set Mutliple selection mode. 

 another fact, is when you insert an item it is selected, if add another both are selected.
So after you add an item set

```
  ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Otherwise, check suggestions given by `Saurabh`

Answer (score 1):

Two items always selected because of below two reasons:

1) They are selected in the inline code - selected =  "true"

2) They are getting selected in the PageLoad method of codebehind and you are calling without Not IspostBack.

Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Set  ListSelectionMode to Multiple and then iterate through the listbox items

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
         {

            if(item.Selected)
            {

              count++;

            }

         }
```